# jQuery plugin development and the contexts

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm trying to develop a jQuery plugin. Here's the code snippet I've written so far:

```
var MYNAMESPACE = MYNAMESPACE || {};
MYNAMESPACE.MyPlugin = function (inputElement, options) {
    var element = $(inputElement),
    oldValue = element.val(),
    container = null,

    init = function () {
        container = $('<div class="container"></div>').hide().insertAfter(element);

        //the suggest method is called from within the anonymous function
        //called by getJSON...
    },

    suggest = function (resp) {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var item = $('<div/>')
                .html('whatever')
                .mouseover(function (index) {
                    return function () {
                        activateItem(index);
                    };
                } (i));

            container.append(item);
        }
    },

    activateItem = function (index) {
        //container doesn't include those appended items.
        //why???
    };

    init();
};

(function ($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function (options) {
        return new MYNAMESPACE.MyPlugin(this.get(0), options);
    };
} (jQuery));
```

Within the activateItem function, the container doesn't have any children!!! Why is that?

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

`container` is already a defined jQuery object, but you are redefining to 'xxxx'. I'm guessing you want to insert the value? Try using `container.html('xxxx')`?

Also, it appears your `mouseover` function is returning a function where the index will be undefined (I haven't test it), but try this instead:

```
.mouseover(function () {
  container.html('xxxx');
  activateItem(i);
});
```

---

Update: Ok, now that I have time to look at the code, it appears `len` is not defined inside the `suggest` function. I made a rudimentary [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JDqcD/) to test it all and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Well, honestly, I'm not going to modify the container's value this way. If you pay attention to the code, it uses container.append(item) to append newly created item to the container. That works fine, but, from within the activateItem function, I need to access to latest modified conatiner. However, the container doesn't have any children (it does, since i see those elements on the screen! however, the container.children().length in activeItem function is 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and the code you've entered is not correct. You cannot access the i in that way. I really need a closure to pass the i value to the activateItem function.

Comment: Then what the purpose of setting container to 'xxxx'?

Comment: The purpose is to show simply that the container value isn't changed in the activateItem function.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect my question more precisely. Any idea what's going wrong there?